# Как сделать чтоб notification нельзя было смахнуть (FCM)?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Вот столкнулся со стандартной проблемой как я понял. Сама имплементации FCM нотификации, очень удобная... Отправляешь нотификацию и получаешь ее на клиенте с помощью вот такого метода

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFMService";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // Handle data payload of FCM messages.


}
}
```

Но как выяснилось этот метод срабатывает только когда приложение в `foregraund` в `backgroung` это не работает...

Но они обьясняют, что если приложение в `backgroung` то нужно сделать следующее.

Отправляете нотификацию, она появляется в статус баре
Юзер на нее кликает
И в вызывающемся активити делаем `getIntent().getExtras()` и получаем по ключам все что положили...

Но проблема в том, что как быть если юзер не открыл нотификацию, а просто смахнул ее? Это означает что данные потеряны навсегда?

Вот кстати [ссылка на офф](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-audience#receive_and_handle_notifications), там в конце говориться об этом

Answer (score 1):

Независимо от того, что вы используете GCM или FCM, нотификацию вам надо создать руками, проставьте флаг `FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT`

```
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, text, when);
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
```

Comment: Не совсем понял, что вы имеете ввиду? Почему я должен ее создавать руками, когда она сама создается? Я в конце своего вопроса привел ссылку где офф документация обьясняет как это работает... И куда конкретно поставить флаг тоже не понял... Можете подробнее описать?

Comment: Как вы отображаете нотификацию? Можете запостить свой код?

Comment: Да никак, она сама отбражается... Это зашито в api firebase... Вы смотрели ссылку которую я прикрепил в конце своего вопроса?

Comment: Еще раз: для того, чтобы ваша нотификация отображалась в бэкграунде, вам нужно создать её руками. Прошу прощения, если я непонятно выразился.
Вот здесь подробно описано как создать нотификацию и передать в неё интент:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Это вам в любом случае понадобится для правильной обработки клика по уведомлению.

После того как создадите нотификацию (в примере по ссылке через вызов mBuilder.build()) установите флаг FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT.

Затем можете вызвать NotificationManager.notify() и получите в точности что хотите

Comment: Также прямо в документации, на которую вы ссылаетесь, есть референс на гитхаб с примером.

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/MyFirebaseMessagingService.java#L41-L69

Перед тем как передать нотификацию в метод notify() (последняя строка функции), установите FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT

Comment: Я извиняюсь, но либо я вас не до конца понимаю, либо вы не знакомы с работой FCM... У FCM нет метода который принимает нотификацию когда приложение бежит в бекграунде. Это описано в документации в конце `Handle notification messages in a backgrounded app` ... Это означает, что FCM предлагает для нотификации свое решение из коробки. API видит когда приложение в бекграунде и само сразу формирует нотификацию и показывает ее так как сформировал сервер на стороне клиента нет метода как то управлять этим... На стороне клиента есть только возможность взять ее если приложение в foreground

Comment: Но мой вопрос как раз о том, как быть если прилоежние в бекграунде? вы советуете создать свою нотификацию и вызывать ее когда необходимо. То есть сервер дегает клиента и клиент делает нотификацию, но у FCM нет метода который реагирует на нотификацию когда приложение в беке... Понимаете о чем я говорю?  Как я пойму в какой момент на клиенте выкинуть эту кастомную нотификацию как вы советуете?

Comment: Посмотрите https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/MyFirebaseMessagingService.java#L41-L69
Нотификация создаётся в методе sendNotification

Comment: А sendNotification вызывается в onMessageReceived. Т.е. не когда необходимо, а когда пришло пуш-уведомление

Comment: И вызывается этот метод всегда, когда получено пуш-уведомление, а не когда оно в форграунде, как вы пишете

Comment: Вы говорите о случае когда приложение в фореграунде тут нет вопросов, но прочтите внимательно пункт Receive and handle notifications из моей ссылки и вы поймете что этот метод вызывается не всегда и вот тут можете тоже почитать https://github.com/google/gcm/issues/63 ... Вот об этом я спрашиваю

Comment: Алексей, мне кажется, ваш вопрос нужно разбить на 2 отдельных:
1. Не вызывается onMessageReceived()
2. Как сделать, чтобы уведомление нельзя было смахнуть
Я ответил на второй, так как он в заголовке вашего топика

Comment: )) Это называется пытаться выкрутиться)) "так как он в заголовке вашего топика" - если бы вы внимательно прочитали тело вопроса(кстати я подробно описал), а не только его заголовок и обратили бы внимание на ссылку которую я прикрепил то мне б сейчас не пришлось бы вам доказывать, что ваш ответ не соответствует моему вопросу... И дело не в том, что "Не вызывается onMessageReceived()" - согласно документации он и не должен вызываться... От сюда и возник вопрос, а как же тогда быть, если он не должен вызываться, но нужно как то закрепить нотификацию. Но все равно спасибо за внимание)